# como quitar las opciones de compartir de un reporte de Power Bi

Tags: php, javascript, powerbi

tengo un reporte realizado en Power Bi, como tengo solo una cuenta no puedo compartirlo de manera Enterprise pero si de manera gratuita, el problema que este reporte aparece con las opciones de compartirlo en redes sociales lo cual me deja descolocado con la seguridad de mi aplicación.

El reporte lo Cargo en un Iframe y estoy buscando la manera de quitar los enlaces de redes sociales mediante javascript una vez el reporte se carga pero no lo he logrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisate este link: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/16498078-disable-share-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, no es posible hacerlo. Al menos de forma oficial.

Al margen de los iconos para compartir en las redes sociales, la seguridad del propio informe está comprometida, puesto que cualquiera puede compartir el link del informe, que no está sometido a ninguna restricción y por lo tanto todo el mundo puede visualizarlo.